# Reuse UITableView code?

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have two view controllers, both of which contain table views. I would like to reuse the code because they are identical, and would like to keep things clean (as well as keep some data from the view controller). How can I go about doing this? Is it "allowed" so to speak, or is it frowned upon?

Comment: create custom tableView owner yourseft

Comment: You should read about `Object-oriented programming`.

Comment: Thanks to the above. I am familiar with both, I was more or less asking if there was a good way to go about it for this instance is all. Not too keen on making custom views. Coming from a Java background, so I want to make sure I start thinking more in an MVC model when I do things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

CustomTableView.h:

```
@interface CustomTableView : UITableView

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSString *someCoolString;
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *superDuperColor;

@end
```

CustomTableView.m:

```
#import "CustomTableView.h"

@implementation CustomTableView

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self)
    {
        // Initialization code
        self.someCoolString = @"theString";
        self.superDuperColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:48.0/255.0 green:32.0/255.0 blue:100.0/255.0 alpha:1.0];
    }
    return self;
}

@end
```

Comment: Awesome! Thanks for the example, this will surely help me get a better idea.

Comment: No problem. If it helped you, click checkmark please

Comment: Can I also put the UITableView update code in this? Meaning the code necessary to set the number of rows, sections, and adding cells to the table?

Comment: Perhaps, try this: `CustomTableView: UITableView <UITableViewDelegate>`

Answer (score 0):

You should create a subclass of `UITableView`.